# c#:Access is denied error when using DirectoryEntry.invoke while updating the password

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using C# code to update the local user password in windows from IIS server box, Below is the snippet using to update the password.

```
DirectoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { decodedTargetUserPassword });
```

I have executed this code from IIS box for more than 100 windows boxes and it is working fine for some boxes and failing with the below error for some boxes.

> ________________________________________________________________________________ AppTrace Error: 0 : Error Message ={0}, Exception has been thrown by
>   the target of an invocation. AppTrace Error: 0 : Error Stack ={0},
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName,
>   Object[] args)    at UserManagementService.Service1.SetPassword(String
>   remoteHost, String targetUser, String newPassword, String username,
>   String password) in
>   c:\UserManagementService\UserManagementService\Service1.svc.cs:line 38
>   AppTrace Error: 0 : Error Stack ={0},
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
>
> ---

The remote connection is successful from IIS box to failing target windows and the user search is also working fine but updating the password is failing. Can anyone help me to find out the cause for this issue.